# Required ruby-3.2.2 is not installed. To install do: 'rvm install "ruby-3.2.2"'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have installed ruby 3.2.2 via rbenv and set both the local and global to this version.
On running command ruby -v it is showing 3.2.2 but when I cd into the new rails app it is showing this:

```
Required ruby-3.2.2 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install "ruby-3.2.2"'
```

But the app runs fine and showing no errors